# dtreeviz: from graphviz.backend cannot import name 'run'

Tags: python, graphviz, dtreeviz

#### dtreeviz library, ImportError: cannot import name 'run'

I tried to follow this [instruction on Github](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) to install and import the dtreeviz library.
When I run the `where dot` and `dot -V` command both seem to work fine as you can see here [Lines in Windows Terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Q1A.png)
However when I try to import dtreeviz in Python (Anaconda, version 3.6.5) I get the following error:

```
from dtreeviz.trees import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fd764fe550c7> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn import tree
----> 2 from dtreeviz.trees import *

C:\Users\marcb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\trees.py in <module>()
      6 from pathlib import Path
      7 from sklearn import tree
----> 8 from graphviz.backend import run, view
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     10 from dtreeviz.shadow import *

ImportError: cannot import name 'run'
```

I hope that someone can help me as I want to use this library to visualize single trees in Python and this library offers much more features than the original graphviz package.

Note: This is my first post on Stackoverflow, so feedback on this is also welcome.

Comment: If you write `pip3 list`, is `graphviz` package in the list?

Comment: Yes, graphviz 0.10.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for an awser, but i had exactly the same problem and fixed it this way:
In `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dtreeviz/trees.py'` i replaced the line
`79: execute(' '.join(cmd), capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=False)`
by
`79: os.system(' '.join(cmd))`.